# Meaning of lyrics to Vangelis (Losing Sleep)

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Could someone please enlighten me to the meaning of the lyrics to "Losing Sleep" by Vangelis (sung by Paul Young):

Here are the lyrics: [www.azlyricdb.com/lyrics/Vangelis-Losing-Sleep-294174](http://www.azlyricdb.com/lyrics/Vangelis-Losing-Sleep-294174)

Comment: I misunderstood the lyrics, assuming the singer is contemplating death (a "sleep" from which one never wakes up).

Answer (score 1):

The recurring theme in this song seems to be returning to (or longing for) a previous love interest. Here's my take:

> A recurring face I see

The love interest.

> You keep turning me round again

They keep thinking about the other person.

> ... my mind ... Is blind to danger

They know that this is bad for them.

> If I knew all there was to learn,
>
> Every twist and turn,
>
> Why do I still try

Even knowing that they should move on, the singer still won't let go.

Answer (score 0):

The feelings behind the lyrics are quite meaningful and deep. The person expressing these feelings is suffering intolerably. Time has not erased from his memory someone he loved very very much. Someone he lost due to his own foolishness regarding love.  After it is too late and the woman he loved has moved on, he cannot escape her memory. Even sleep cannot help him forget her face. Her smile. Her scent. Deep down, she is quite aware that the memory of her is driving him inside. He realizes he should get help because he is playing with his very existence. His very life is at stake as is his sanity.  Despite the fact that his life has taken many "twists and turns", the things that refuse to change concern her.  His memories of her consume him both day and night at the unlikeliest moments.  The song is very meaningful to me personally. Because you see, there is a woman in my past as well who has made me feel just as he does. The thing to take away from this for you the reader of these words is that you should be very cautious when giving you a feelings, your heart, to another person. Because if you invest too much of your emotions and things don't work out in the end, then you too will know what it is like to be Losing Sleep because of the fact that you lost the love of your life.